# KMM build fails after adding KMMBridge plugin, if dependencies exist

Tags: ios, kotlin, gradle, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to create a KMM project that publishes to Cocoapods using [KMMBridge](https://kmmbridge.touchlab.co). This works fine for a basic project that only returns a strings, but when adding dependencies to make a http requests or parse json, it stops working.

I followed the [Get started with Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-getting-started.html) and after finishing, I started adding the KMMBridge code to the Gradle script. Just adding the KMMBridge plugin

`id("co.touchlab.faktory.kmmbridge") version "0.3.7"`

breaks the build with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This fat framework already has a binary for architecture `arm64` (shared for target `ios_arm64`)
```

Project can be found here: https://github.com/ionel71089/KotlinMultiplatformSandbox

Here is the `build.gradle.kts` file for the `shared` module:

```
val ktorVersion = "2.2.4"

version = "0.1"

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.8.20"
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")

    id("co.touchlab.faktory.kmmbridge") version "0.3.4" // breaks build
//    `maven-publish`
}

kotlin {
    android {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.4.0")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }

        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
            }
        }

        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val androidUnitTest by getting

        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting

        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }

        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting

        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }

    cocoapods {
        summary = "KMMBridgeSampleKotlin"
        homepage = "https://touchlab.dev"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "13"
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.kotlinmultiplatformsandbox"
    compileSdk = 33
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
    }
}

/*
addGithubPackagesRepository()
kmmbridge {
    mavenPublishArtifacts()
    githubReleaseVersions()
    spm()
    cocoapods("git@github.com:ionel71089/PublicPodspecs.git")
    versionPrefix.set("0.8")
}
 */
```

**Note:** I've also tried adding the dependencies to a trivial KMMBridge sample project, but that didn't work either (https://github.com/ionel71089/KMMBridgeSampleKotlin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're duplicating your framework definitions. See the KMMBridge Troubleshooting doc:

https://kmmbridge.touchlab.co/docs/TROUBLESHOOTING#error-this-fat-framework-already-has-a-binary-for-architecture-x64-common-for-target-ios_x64-or-similar-for-arm